# page_action doesn't work in developer mode

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, manifest, google-chrome-devtools

the problem is very simple: if make extension for chrome and use

```
chrome.pageAction
```

to put icons inside the address bar, This Extensions dont work in developmode. Why NOT ?

background.html

```
<script language="javascript">

chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        file: "jquery.js"
    }, function () {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
            code: '$[CODE JQUERY];'
        });
    });
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if(tab.url.indexOf("facebook.com") != -1) {
        chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: Where do you call this API? Note that you are not allowed to use it in content scripts.

Comment: i use this in background.html

Comment: You'll need to show the code of your background script then. Also please debug the background page and check for errors.

Comment: You can't use inline code in your HTML. You need to move it to some external file (like background.js) and include it in page using `<script src='background.js'></script>`.

Comment: Ok now it works! Before it only worked if published. You are my reference point. thanks @KonradDzwinel

Answer (score 1):

Contributing to Konrad Dzwinel comment, you can't use inline code in your HTML. Move it to an external javascript and then try again.

By the way, Page Actions do work in development mode, I use them all the time! Here's an example in my Background.js that checks the page URL on tabs updated; if the URL is what I'm looking for, I show the Page Action.

```
/**
* Listener for Displaying the Extension Page Action when the Tab is updated.
* @private
* @event displayPageAction
* @param {Number} tabId The tabId given by the tabs listener to know which tab was updated.
* @param {Object} changeInfo The current status of the tab.
* @param {Object} tab The metadata of the tab.
**/
var displayPageAction = function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
var regexAIESEC = new RegExp(/http:\/\/www.myaiesec.net\//); // My page URL
var match = regexAIESEC.exec(tab.url); 
// We only display the Page Action if we are inside a MyAIESEC Page AND it finished loading.
if(match && changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
   chrome.pageAction.show(tab.id);     
}
};
```

You callback this code through the tabs onUpdated even handler.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(displayPageAction);
```